# Are there any restrictions on my implementation of IList.RemoveAt as part of the API contract?

Tags: c#, .net, api-design

**Backstory**

I have a viewmodel with a list of items. Each item has a state; none, added, modified, deleted, etc. When an item that previously existed is to be deleted from the list, it stays in the list but is marked deleted and it is clear that it will be deleted when the users clicks Save.

The list itself is bound to a UI control which operates on `IBindingList`. When the user adds and deletes rows via the UI control, the UI control calls `IList.Add` and `IList.RemoveAt`.

**Question**

Since I want to keep preexisting rows and mark them differently, I have two options:

1. My implementation of `IList.RemoveAt` can simply mark the item deleted and keep it in the list and fail to raise a `ListChanged` remove event. This seems simplest and cleanest, but I wonder if there is an API expectation that the index is actually removed. Imagine a general-purpose loop like `while (list.Count != 0) { Process(list[0]); list.RemoveAt(0); }` Obviously I'll have to avoid that, but the need to avoid it seems like a kind of bad coupling. Am I then sinning against API? Or is that snippet just bad code  that can be ignored because it makes too many assumptions?
2. My implementation could allow the remove to take place and raise the event, then mark the item deleted, reinsert the item and raise the insert event. This doesn't harm the contract, since it's understood that the list may be mutated by multiple components and the events keep everyone in sync. However, it's extra UI flicker and feels a bit hacky.
3. I can modify the UI control (it's third party but extensible) so that it looks for an `ISoftDelete` interface on the list. If the interface exists, it calls `ISoftDelete.SetDeleted(int index, bool)` rather than calling `RemoveAt`. This seems fairly clean but it's extra complexity with a cost not only in the list API but in every UI control that will ever need to understand this list. Is this separation worth the cost? And what would happen if `RemoveAt` was called anyway- the row would disappear from sight which is not a good scenario, so it would have to throw an exception or borrow #2's workaround.

**Edit**

Strange! take a look at [`IList.RemoveAt(int index)` with `CONTRACTS_FULL`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/ilist.cs,167)- it has the following:

```
    void IList.RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        //Contract.Requires(index >= 0);
        //Contract.Requires(index < ((IList)this).Count);
        //Contract.Ensures(((IList)this).Count == Contract.OldValue(((IList)this).Count) - 1);  // Not threadsafe
    }
```

Note the 'not threadsafe' comment! Does that mean they would uncomment that line, if possible? But nothing in an indexed-based list can be threadsafe.

Comment: Fundamentally the collection is a read only collection.  "Removing" an item isn't removing that item, it's mutating that item to indicate that it is hidden/soft deleted.

Comment: ...except for `IList.Add` though... I definitely need `IBindingList.AllowNew = true` and `IList.Add`. Once I have that, I must provide an impl for `IList.RemoveAt`- which the UI control will call by default. I also need `AllowRemove = true` so that the UI control knows it can delete items.

Comment: I was searching the BCL for any place where RemoveAt returns without removing an item or throwing an exception. So far haven't found one, but found something strange- see my edit. Don't know what bearing it has. Seems like the kind of thing @HansPassant usually knows.